# SOQL - Not returning formula field

Tags: soql

Not sure if this is a bug or if I am doing something wrong. In my sandbox when I query a formula field I am not getting a value returned. When I look at the record page I can see that the formula is working. The formula field is "Created_Date_Day_of_Week__c". Any ideas?

Formula Field:
The formula field is set to Text.

```
CASE( MOD( DATEVALUE(TEXT(CreatedDate)) - DATE( 1900, 1, 7 ), 7 ), 0, "Sunday", 1, "Monday", 2, "Tuesday", 3, "Wednesday", 4, "Thursday", 5, "Friday", 6, "Saturday", "Error" )
```

Record Page:
[image]

SOQL Query:
[image]

Comment: Perhaps you should share the formula itself...

Comment: I've seen this before; the UI is more tolerant of date calcs than soql or reports. I'll bet if you run a report on this object, the Created Date - Day of Week will come back as #Error. Adrian is right, need to see formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some random searching I came across a success community page with this version of the formula. This one works. Don't really know why.

```
CASE(MOD(DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)-DATE(1900, 1, 6), 7), 0, "Saturday", 1, "Sunday", 2,"Monday", 3, "Tuesday", 4, "Wednesday", 5, "Thursday", 6,"Friday","")
```

Thanks @cropredy for letting me know that the UI and SOQL behave differently.

Comment: The most notable difference is that your fallback value is `""`. If you change that in your original formula does it then work? Starting on Saturday instead of Sunday shouldn't make a difference...